# Set cookie on IP based URL

Tags: php, cookies

I want to set cookies on IP based URL.Here is my code:

```
if(check_login($_POST))    
{

    setcookie("client_id", $clientid, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '.domain.com');
    setcookie("email", $email1, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '.domain.com');
    setcookie("domain", $sdomain, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '.domain.com');
    setcookie("serverid", $serverid, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '.domain.com');
    setcookie("password", $password1, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '.domain.com');
    setcookie("current_login_status", $c_current_login_status, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '.domain.com');

    **Instead of above ,I want to set cookies like following**

    setcookie("client_id", $clientid, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '192.168.1.20');
    setcookie("email", $email1, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '192.168.1.20');
    setcookie("domain", $sdomain, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '192.168.1.20');
    setcookie("serverid", $serverid, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '192.168.1.20');
    setcookie("password", $password1, time()+3600*24*1, '/', '192.168.1.20');
}
```

Please suggest if it is possible.

Comment: Please, do no store passwords in cookies. 
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9455/is-it-safe-to-store-the-password-hash-in-a-cookie-and-use-it-for-remember-me-l

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=128608

> Is it possible to set a cookie to an IP number instead of the usual www.company.com?
>
> You might be able to set the cookie (that is, get some browser to
>   accept and store it), but no browser that I know of will actually
>   return it to you. Where they to do so, it would introduce a massive
>   security hole.
>
> Think about it for a moment. It's possible to set a cookie for
>   ".example.com" that will be returned by a browser for visits to
>   "example.com", "www.example.com", or "a.b.c.example.com". But what of
>   ".1.1"? That would match sites all over the place.

So esentially, no.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Let me clear some points
1.I am checking user name and password from one domain and redirecting user to another domain by setting the required cookies.
2.Due to some problem my redirection domain is not working by its name,I can get only by typing IP address on URL.

So that I am trying to do the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "redirecting to another domain by setting the required cookies"? Cookies don't cause redirection. Anyway, a server can only set cookies for its own domain. If it sets it by IP, it will probably only work if you access the web page by IP.

Comment: I think what you should do is redirect to your other domain with encrypted user / password values, and log them in the other domain.