# Cookies not sent back to domain in IFrame

Tags: php, html, cookies, iframe, session-cookies

I have an application running on `192.168.1.100`. This application serves a page in which an iframe is embedded which is basically another application running on totally different ip e.g. `10.0.0.1.`

The issue is whenever user performs a login inside iframe a cookie is set but it is not sent back to 10.0.0.1 for subsequent requests.

What i am trying to achieve is this even possible?

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: [Set cookie on IP based URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989201/set-cookie-on-ip-based-url)

Comment: You cannot share cookies between different domains. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Comment: @really_operator its not about cross domain cookies :)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for your time, link which you shared was helped in understanding the problem.

Comment: @dakait sure it is.  You have one domain (192.168.1.100) loading an iframe from another domain (10.0.0.1).  They are just IP addresses in this case instead of named domains.

Comment: @really_operator correct, but each domain (IP) is handling its own cookie(s) they are not sent cross-domain(IP)

Comment: An iframe on a domain does not count as the same domain if it originates from a different domain.  You cannot read cookies across domains, and this includes iframes embedded on the page that are from a different domain.

Comment: @really_operator totally agree what you said. My question was not related to reading cross domain cookies :)